# How to register users for mobile push notification

Tags: mobilepush, mobilepush-android, mobilepush-ios

I am trying to create an ios app for mobile push notification using the following resource:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pushImplGuide.meta/pushImplGuide/pns_overview.htm

What I am trying to understand is how do I register the user-devices, who are going to get the notification.

Comment: Did you go through this link https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pushImplGuide.meta/pushImplGuide/pns_dev_registration.htm

Answer (score 1):

The Marketing Cloud Mobile Push product has an SDK which should help streamline your implementation and handles all the registration details for a device/contact:

https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/